# How to set minimum width for CKEditor?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

My website is being built to support mobile as well. The problem is that I need to set the `minWidth` of the editor in order to be able to put the one I want.

Can anybody guide me or tell me what config to add in order to set minimum width for the editor?

Answer (score 3):

The two config options you are looking for are [`config.width`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.width) and [`config.resize_minWidth`](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.resize_minWidth).

So for instance, to start the editor at 500px wide and prevent it from being resized any smaller:

```
config.width = 500;
config.resize_minWidth = 500;
```

Comment: I figurid out, just needed to insert int under a div with the widtdh and min width specified